# Jmeter: multiple values for a single Varchar parameter in CSV

Tags: csv, parameters, jmeter

I have to parameterize my values

my CSV file looks like(last six parameters are VARCHAR)

```
74861,1,'123,122,127',0,0,0,0,0
```

Jmeter considers `123,122,127` as separate argument and gives following error:

> Error: number of arguments (10) and number of types (8) are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [double quotes](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) instead of quote,as :

```
74861,1,"123,122,127",0,0,0,0,0
```

> JMeter allows values to be quoted; this allows the value to contain a delimiter. If "allow quoted data" is enabled, a value may be enclosed in double-quotes. These are removed. To include double-quotes within a quoted field, use two double-quotes. For example:
>
> - 1,"2,3","4""5" =>
> - 1
> - 2,3
> - 4"5

Comment: I tried double quotes too like this 74861,1,"123,122",0,0,0,0,0 
 but still I get same error. Any alternative idea plz?

Comment: You need to change `allow quoted data` to true in CSV config

Comment: I did change allow quoted data to True. Still no luck